# Instance variable in view turns nil when used

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

total noob question here, enough that it is still difficult for me to explain the situation.

My controller sends the user to the Show page

```
class PriceListsController < ApplicationController

include PriceListsHelper


def show
    if params[:customer_id].blank?

        @dispatch_location = "F02"
        @price_list = PriceList.find(params[:id]).price_list
        @full_price_list = PriceList.where("price_list = ?", @price_list).all
        else

        @dispatch_location_price_list =  Customer.find(params[:customer_id]).dispatch_location_price_list
        @price_list = Customer.find(params[:customer_id]).customer_selling_price_list
        @full_price_list = PriceList.where("price_list = ?", @price_list).all
    end
  end
end
```

From here my show page loops through each price list and returns details about that price list.

```
<%= render 'price_lists/sidebar' %>
<% provide(:title, "Show Price List") %>
<h1><%=@dispatch_location_price_list + " " + params[:id] %></h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">

<table class="table table-hover table-condensed .table-responsive">
  <tr>
    <th>Product Price Group</th>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Discount</th>
    <th>UOM</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>

    <% @full_price_list.each do |full_price_list| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= full_price_list.product_price_group %></td>
            <% @product_details = Product.find_by_product_price_group(full_price_list.product_price_group) %>
            <td><%= @product_details.product_name %>/td>
            <td><%= full_price_list.discount_value %>%</td>
            <td><%= full_price_list.unit_of_measure %></td>
            <% calculated_price(full_price_list.product_price_group) %>
            <td><%= number_to_currency(@dispatch_price - (@dispatch_price * (full_price_list.discount_value/100)),:unit => "$") %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

I use a helper method to calculate within the loop based on values created in the loop

```
module PriceListsHelper

def calculated_price(product_price_group)
    @dispatch_price = PriceList.where(:price_list =>         @dispatch_location,:product_price_group => product_price_group).first

    if @dispatch_price.nil? || @dispatch_price == 0
            @dispatch_price = 0
            else
            @dispatch_price = @dispatch_price.trade_price
        end
    end

    def product_details(product_price_group)
        @product_details = Product.find_by_product_price_group(product_price_group)
      end
end
```

I am getting the error "undefined method `product_name' for nil:NilClass" however if I place a

```
<% fail %>
```

Between (I am debugging this with Better Errors)

```
<% @product_details = Product.find_by_product_price_group(full_price_list.product_price_group) %>
<td><%= @product_details.product_name %>/td>
```

and in the error view I can use the live shell to call @product_details.product_name and it will return the product name perfectly. As soon as I remove the fail argument and let it run as normal I get the error.

Any ideas what might be happening? It is as if the variable exists up until I want to actually use it. So confused :/ any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

My gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
gem 'simple_form'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 You find

```
@product_details = Product.find_by_product_price_group(full_price_list.product_price_group)
```

in iteration block. Other words you do it several times and each time you overwrite `@product_details`

2 `find_by_...` can return nil.

Conclusion: at least one `full_price_list` does not have Product by `product_price_group`.

Comment: Thanks gotva, so would that mean if I add a if statement testing for nil and replacing with zero than it might allow for a zero to be returned instead? I will try that now and see what happens. Thank you for your clarity.

Comment: ah and ofcourse when I am running the fail command it is stopping on the first loop and when I take it away it is stopping on an actual error. God you feel so stupid when you figure that out haha.

Comment: Yes, when error is raised then all processes are stopped. You need check 1. if it is normal logically that `find_by_...` returns nil for some `full_price_list.product_price_group` (if it is not normal then add validations or callbacks to model) 2. if it is ok that `full_price_list` does not have Product by `product_price_group` so you need to check on nil and do not render `@product_details.product_name`

Comment: excellent thank you. I have wrapped it on the html.erb page with     <% if @product_details.nil?%> 

<% end %>
It is all working great now. Thanks again :)